# Regex ignore last withe space

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

[image]

from which I get all the sentence except the last word, but I have problems if this word has a space at the end.
example:
[image]

Comment: If following word is provided, then still I get
```Carlos Gonzalez newWord```

```Carlos ```. Is it expected? Or should I get ```Carlos Gonzalez ```

Comment: yes, this work with only a word, if i try add more words not work: https://regexr.com/65tvm

Comment: Carlos Gonzalez

Comment: @Alireza https://regexr.com/65u05 not work with the base case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern: `\S+ \b`

See Regex [Demo](https://regexr.com/65tvj)

**Explanation**

- `\S+` one or more from all non-whitespace characters.
- an empty space.
- `\b` word boundary. a position between words character (\w) and non words character (\W)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex. Made sure last white space is ignored

```
(^.*)[!<=\S]
```

Following regex can be used to ignore all whitespaces

```
\S*
```

Comment: now i have: https://regexr.com/65tuf

Comment: @CarlosFelipeGonzalez You want to ignore all the whitespaces? If yes, Please try out the second regex I provided.

Comment: i want ignore the last withespace and get the first image as result

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookahead asserting 1 or more spaces without newlines followed by a non whitespace char to the right:

```
^.+(?=[^\S\r\n]+\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cWT2Te/1)

If you also want to match a single word at the start of the string, you can add an alternation `|` and match only 1 or more nonwhiteapace chars:

```
^(?:.+(?=[^\S\r\n]+\S)|\S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cZILl4/1)

Another option could be using a capture group, with an optional part matching non whotespace chars between spaces:

```
^(.+?)(?: +\S+ *)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zl1lxM/1)